# Use Model Display name for Blazor Validation message from Custom InputSelect

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

As we know Blazor doesn't support Int option select for `<InputSelect>` (but support string & Enum) and we get the following error message:

Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputSelect`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]] does not support the type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.

Therefore, I write a `<CustomInputSelect>`:

```
public class CustomInputSelect<TValue> : InputSelect<TValue>
    {
        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result, out string validationErrorMessage)
        {
            if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int?))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(value, out var resultInt))
                {
                    result = (TValue)(object)resultInt;
                    validationErrorMessage = null;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = default;
                    validationErrorMessage = $"The {FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is Required.";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result, out validationErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the following Model:

```
public class Risk : ICloneable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Associated Legal Entity of the risk
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Legal Entity")]
        public int? LegalEntityId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Associated Legal Entity Short Code of the risk
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Legal Entity Short Code")]
        public string LegalEntityShortCode { get; set; }
}
```

The following Blazor page:

```
    <CustomInputSelect id="ddlLegalEntity" class="form-control InputTextHeigth" @bind-Value="ShowRisk.LegalEntityId">
            @foreach (var option in LEList)
            {
                <option value="@option.Id">
                 @option.OptionName
                </option>
            }
    </CustomInputSelect>
<div class="cs-col-6">
    <ValidationMessage class="form-control" For="@(() => ShowRisk.LegalEntityId)" />
</div>
```

Everything is working fine. I can use int value on Option list. However, The validation error is generating as Field name instead of Display name.
So I getting "The **LegalEntityId** field is Required." instead of "The **Legal Entity** field is Required".

From the first snapshot of the code, the message is generated:

```
validationErrorMessage = $"The {FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is Required.";
```

How can I display Model Display name instead of FieldName?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11414
This may have been resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Your `CustomInputSelect` inherits from `InputSelect`. `InputSelect` inherits from `InputBase`.
This abstract class has a property called `DisplayName`.

It should be filled by either setting it manually in the razor file or via a `Display` attribute on your view model.

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="@moveOutViewModel.MoveOutDate" DisplayName="@localize["moveout_step_date_legend"]" />
```

or

```
[Display(Name = "address_street", ResourceType = typeof(Translations))]
public string Street { get; set; }
```

In your custom select class, you can use the following code:

```
if (int.TryParse(value, out var resultInt))
{
    result = (TValue)(object)resultInt;
    validationErrorMessage = null;
    return true;
}
else
{
    result = default;
    validationErrorMessage = $"The '{this.DisplayName ?? this.FieldIdentifier.FieldName}' field is required.";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bjorn, Thanks for the reply. Where you get the 'input' variable from? Looks like your solution is very close but can't really work how can I get this input variable??

Comment: @Shuvra I've changed the code. The original code was an extension method, hence the use of input. You can use `this.DisplayName` or simply `DisplayName` when you inherit from InputSelect.

Comment: Can't see the DisplayName property in InputBase. My Assembley: Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web, Version=3.1.6.0. am I using an older version

Comment: @Shuvra I see. We are using version 5.0.3 of the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms" package. However, to use this version you need to target `.Net 5`.

Comment: thank you mate. you answer was very useful.